# Jinja-like JS templating language

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2, template-engine, language-comparisons

I really like django/jinja2 templating languages. Their syntax is extremely simple and yet is highly versatile. Is there anything similar to that in both syntax and capability in javascript, or if not both, at least in the capability.

I looked at underscore, jquery templates, and mustache templates, and none of them seemed to be what I am looking for.

**Additional notes**

I think out of all libs (I looked at) mustache is the best but I don't really like the syntax. For example this mustache template

```
{{#people}}
    {{name}}
{{/people}}
{{^people}}
    No people :(
{{/people}}
```

compared to django's templates:

```
{% for person in people %}
    {{ person.name }}
{% empty %}
     No people :(
{% endfor %}`
```

Also the same thing for applying filters. For example:

```
{{#filter}}{{value}}{{/filter}}
```

vs

```
{{ value|filter }}
```

I think django/jinja2 approach is more clean and just feels more natural.

So, is there any js library which does templates very similar to django/jinja? If not, I guess I have to live with muschache (or maybe some other good js library - I am open to suggesstions), but it just doesn't feel right.

Thank you.

Comment: What features are missing in mustache?

Comment: There is a [JavaScript port for Jinja](https://github.com/ericclemmons/jinja.js) but i haven't personally tried it yet.

Comment: Looks very good. The only thing don't like too much is the size. Using Closure compiler, only managed to compress to 18kb. I was just googling and came across https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js and https://github.com/tbranyen/combyne.js. Any thoughts on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link from @pradeek's comment. It is a port of jinja to js.

https://github.com/ericclemmons/jinja.js

Comment: 167.667 kb - better enable gzip

Answer (score 22):

Have a look at [Nunjucks](http://jlongster.github.io/nunjucks/), a JS templating engine heavily inspired by Jinja2. It supports block inheritance, macros, filters and much more and works both server (NodeJS) and client-side (most browsers).

Comment: For anyone else as late to the party as I am, Nunjucks is the only project listed here that still has activity on github. It's run by Mozilla, so probably not going away anytime soon...

Comment: Nunjucks is no longer being maintained

Comment: @felipecrp Nunjucks is definitely still being maintained. Commits, PRs, plenty of activity https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks

Comment: @KayakinKoder Now it has. :) But by the time of the comment, they were looking for a maintener. https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/commit/f44646ba95e564cbe7bbe70ad3fda4359878ed5a#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8

Answer (score 7):

My JavaScript Jinja implementation can be found here:
https://github.com/sstur/jinja

It supports both Jinja and Liquid syntax, runs on the browser and in Node, will compile templates to dependency-free JavaScript, and is about 3K gzipped

http://sstur.com/jinja/demo/

Tests included. Express.js support in progress..

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Not maintained anymore**

[Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) is an awesome, Django/Jinja-like template engine for node.js and the browser.

```
<h1>{{ pagename|title }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for author in authors %}
    <li{% if loop.first %} class="first"{% endif %}>{{ author }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can add custom tags to achieve various types of template syntax:

```
{% filter %}{{value}}{% endfilter %}
{% filter 'value' %}
{{ value | filter }}
```

Side-note: You can use Django's `request.is_ajax()` to conditionally send back an un-rendered Django template and use Swig to render it with a JSON object.

Comment: I second this, especially because of the Express compatibility!

Answer (score 2):

> a javascript template library, aimed at being compatible with django's template language

[Plate](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/plate)

Answer (score 1):

This is very new: angularjs
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.nl/2012/06/better-web-templating-with-angularjs-10.html

Answer (score 0):

twig.js looks really interesting too and weighs less than plate
https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jinja2 with Python and now I am using jinjs on a different project on the Node.js platform.

https://github.com/ravelsoft/node-jinjs